# How run AWK command in Shell Script?

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

I am trying to create files using AWK with in a for loop but getting empty file. It looks like AWK is not getting executed. Can you please advise, what is incorrect here?

I have a file `$LOG/order_"$id".txt` which has some lines between 2 strings `CUT:1` and `CUT2` etc.. I just need these lines in separate files so I wrote this for loop.

```
for (( i=1; i<=$CNTLN; i++ ))
do
    j=`expr $i - 1`
    /usr/bin/awk '/CUT:$j/, /CUT:$i/' $LOG/order_"$id".txt >  $LOG/order_"$id"_"$i".txt
done
```

This generate blank file however if I copy and past this command on shell, it works.

Please advise.

Comment: Shot in the dark: did you try replacing the simple quote by double quote around the "/CUT:$j...." part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoting is correct, however you should use variable passing instead of trying to embed shell variables within the AWK script.

```
for (( i=1; i<=CNTLN; i++ ))
do
    (( j = i - 1 ))
    /usr/bin/awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" '$0 ~ "CUT:" j, $0 ~ "CUT:" i' "$LOG/order_$id.txt" >  "$LOG/order_${id}_$i.txt"
done
```

When using AWK variables, you have to use the tilde match operator instead of the slash-delimited form.

You don't say which shell you're using, but based on the `for` statement, I'd guess Bash, Korn or Z shell. If it's one of those, then you can do integer arithmetic as I've shown without using the external `expr` utility. In the case of ksh or zsh, you can do float math, too.

You could eliminate the line that calculates `j` and include it in the `for` statement.

```
for (( i=1, j=0, i<=CNTLN; i++, j++ ))
```

In a couple of places you use all-caps variable names. I recommend making a habit of not doing this in order to avoid name collisions with shell or environment variables. It's not an issue in this specific case, but it's a good habit to be in.

Actually, now that I think about it. The shell loop could be eliminated and the whole thing written in AWK.